# Cannot create a row of size 8084 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an existing table like below, which has a column char(4000) to save the document path, the table has a lot of data.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Document_Master] (
  [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [TMasterID] [bigint] NULL,
  [DocumentName] [varchar](100) NULL,
  [DocumentPath] [nchar](4000) NULL,
  [IsMisc] [bit] NOT NULL,
  [ReceivedDate] [date] NULL
GO
```

now I want to change the DocumentPath column from char(4000) to nvarchar(255) when I try to alter the column type I get the below error.

```
 ALTER TABLE  Document_Master
 ALTER column DocumentPath nvarchar(255)
 go
```

error -

```
 Warning: The table "Document_Master" has been created, but its maximum row size exceeds the allowed maximum of 8060 bytes. INSERT or UPDATE to this table will fail if the resulting row exceeds the size limit.
 Msg 511, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
 Cannot create a row of size 8084 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.
 The statement has been terminated.
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: The error is clear. Do you really expect paths with 2^64 of characters? This isn't supported by any file system. `nvarchar(max)` is *only* meant to store BLOB data, not as a "don't care about the size" type

Comment: What you really need to do is change `nchar(4000)` to `nvarchar(4000)` and trim the trailing spaces stored in the original `nchar(4000)` values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - it wouldn't allow me to change it to any other type either. i don't want to leave it as nchar(4000)

Comment: same error when i tried changing it to varchar(4000)

Comment: How did you try to change this? `CREATE` doesn't change columns, it creates a new table.  If you tried with SSMS's table designer it would create a new table, copy the data over and then rename it. You *can't* create a table whose rows exceed the limit, no matter the type. It's *not* about the types, it's about the actual size. Frankly, unless you *really really* expect paths that are 4K long, you shouldn't use such a long field.

Comment: Switching from `nvarchar` to `varchar` is no solution either, unless you're absolutely certain you'll never have to store Unicode paths and file names

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I am not creating the table, just wanted to share the table schema with others, its an existing table.

Comment: Use realistic lengths. That's it. You can't override the maximum row length. `nchar(4000)` is 8000 bytes, which means just that and the DocumentName are enough to reach the limit. Y

Comment: ok thanks, now i get it, will use realistic values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now I want to change the DocumentPath column from char(4000) to nvarchar(max)

That is NOT what you do, you know...

> ALTER TABLE  Document_Master
> ALTER column DocumentPath nvarchar(4000)

This is NOT setting it to max, sorry. It does say 4000, not max. 4000 already is comically long for a path (seriously, that is a path that is 1.7 printed pages long. I would suggest having a really good look on this and not going max, but realistic.